# Spark Streaming - Classification of tweets' stream from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, sentiment-analysis

I am new at Spark and I absolutely need some help for  classifying tweets from a Kafka Stream. Following I will explain the step processes i have done until now as well as the point where I'm stuck.

I hope some of you guys can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

**The context is the following**:

I have a simple *Kafka Producer* which simulates a tweet's stream (read from a file)  and a *TweetAnalyzer Consumer* which should process and classify the tweets on a **Spark Streaming Context**, as soon as it receive them.

In order to classify the received tweets, I have earlier built-up and stored on the disk a *TF-IDF* and *Naive Bayes* models which are loaded before the *Spark Streaming Context* starts.

For each tweet processed (stemming, punctuation, etc), I should compute its *TF-IDF vector* (feature vector) and classify it by exploiting respectively the IDF and Naive Bayes Models previously loaded.

Going straight to the point, my problem occurs when I have to transform the tweet's *term frequency vectors* (TF) to its *TF-IDF vectors*.

This is the code:

**Kafka Producer**

```py
text_file = list(
    csv.reader(
        open('/twitterDataset/twitter/test_data.txt', 'rU')
    )
)

for row in text_file:
    time.sleep(1)
    jd = json.dumps(row).encode('ascii')
    producer.send(kafka_topic,jd)
```

**TweetAnalyzer**

```py
#setting configuration
...  
#reading configuration
...
#setting Kafka configuration
...

# Create Spark context
sc = SparkContext(
    appName = app_name,
    master  = spark_master
)

# Create Streaming context
ssc = StreamingContext(
    sc,
    int(spark_batch_duration)
)

# Loading TF MODEL and compute TF-IDF
....

kafkaParams = {'metadata.broker.list"': kafka_brokers}

# Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    ssc,
    [kafka_topic],
    {"metadata.broker.list": kafka_brokers}
)

obj1 = TweetPreProcessing()

lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])

tweet = lines.flatMap(obj1.TweetBuilder)

hashingTF = HashingTF()

#computing TF for each tweet
tf_tweet = tweet.map(lambda tup: hashingTF.transform(tup[0:]))\
                .map(lambda x: IDF().fit(x))
                .pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

In the last lines of code I cannot apply the **IDF().fit(x)** function on **x** since Spark expects an "RDD of term frequency vectors" whereas in this point I have a "Trasformed DStream" due the the Streaming Spark Context.

I've tried to use either the *transform()* or *foreachRDD()* function instead of *map()*, but i don't know how to return correctly a new DStream after the transformation.

For example:

```py
tf_tweet = tweet.map(lambda tup: hashingTF.transform(tup[0:]))\
                .transform(classify_tweet)
                .pprint()

def classify_tweet(tf):

    #compute TF-IDF of the tweet
    idf = IDF().fit(tf)
    tf_idf = idf.transform(tf)

    #print(tf_idf.collect())

    return idf
```

If I run the code using the transform function, Spark triggers (at the top of the back-trace) this error:

> File
>   "/workspace_spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 67, in call return r._jrdd 
>  AttributeError: 'IDFModel' object
>   has no attribute '_jrdd'

But if I omit the return statement and simply print the *tf_idf vector* it gives me the correct output which looks like this:

> [SparseVector(1048576, {164998: 0.0, 364601: 0.0, 924192: 0.0, 963449:
>   0.0})]
>  [SparseVector(1048576, {251465: 0.0, 821055: 0.0, 963449: 0.0})]
>  [SparseVector(1048576, {234762: 0.0, 280973: 0.0, 403903: 0.0, 712732: 0.0, 861562: 0.0, 1040690: 0.0})] ...

If i've got it right, I think the problem is that I cannot *return* a *SparseVector* when it expects a *DStream*.

Anyhow, is there a solution for this problem ?

I'd be very thankful if somebody can help me out with this, I am tragically stuck.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return transformed `tf_idf`:

```
>>> def classify_tweet(tf):
...     return IDF().fit(tf).transform(tf)
```